# Which language do most polysyllabic words in the english language come from?

Tags: etymology

I am doing an english project and can't find any information on this topic. Help is much appreciated!! thanks

Comment: Excluding proper names and compounds, the general tendency is that the more syllables it has, the more likely it comes from Latin or Greek. If you want information about this, go get David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language_; it ought to be in every English classroom in the world.

Comment: @JohnLawler Has to be good! DC was ten years at my *alma mater* the University of Reading.

Comment: This question is easy. They come from the **English** language. All of them. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

An interactive graphic at the top of [blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/03/borrowed-words](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/03/borrowed-words/) shows source-language proportions of words borrowed into English, either cumulatively or per 50-year period.  As Latin and French have provided by far the largest proportions of loan words (and because Latin and French words often are multisyllabic) they have also provided the largest numbers of high-syllable-count words.

Also see:
• *[rice.edu/~kemmer](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/structure/borrowed.html)*, *Major Periods of Borrowing*
• wikipedia, *[Foreign language influences in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_language_influences_in_English)*
• *[anglik.net](http://www.anglik.net/englishlanguagehistory.htm)*, *A Brief History of the English Language*